# Is it possible to modify the output of pagination urls?

Tags: ee2, channel, pagination

I'm currently using the following code for pagination:

```
{pagination_links}
    {page}
        <a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
    {/page}
{/pagination_links}
```

Because of an addon I'm using, I need to modify the output of the {pagination_url} variable.

{pagination_url} outputs http://sitename.com/blog/P20, and I need to add a segment before blog.

I attempted to use the [Find and Replace Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/find-and-replace-plus) addon, but due to the parse order, I'm not able to use the {site_url} variable to find/replace.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just need to modify the part of the URL before the pagination segment (and your use case is relatively simple) you can use the `paginate_base` parameter on your entries loop ([docs here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#paginate-base)):

```
{exp:channel:entries paginate_base="blog/foo"
  {pagination_links}
    {page}
        <a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
    {/page}
  {/pagination_links}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now your output should look like this: `http://example.com/blog/foo/P20`

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked that parameter, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help...

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling brave, you can also head to:

system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Pagination.php

All of the opening and closing elements are there and you can override them. Just make a note of those changes so you can restore them after an upgrade.